# Load GCMLE locally and obtain activations

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I would like to view activations locally (say jupyter notebook) from a `saved_model` deployed to GCMLE's prediction service so that I can experiment with visualizations. I have successfully loaded the `saved_model` into the graph:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
  tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], _VERSION)
```

I also have a dictionary `request` of inputs that I could typically just feed to the deployed prediction service (`predict_json()` included at end for simplicity:

```
responses = predict_json(project, model, instances = [request], version)
```

Is there any way that I can use my `saved_model` locally and feed in the input `request` and then look at the activations of specific layers (such as the logits or the output of a convolution)? I believe that what I am trying to do is something like this:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], _VERSION)
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    inputs = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_layer:0")
    activations = graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv1d/bias:0")

    print(sess.run(inputs, activations))
```

However, I don't can't figure out the tensor name for the equivalent of the serving input function like `body={'instances': instances}` in the `predict_json`. Further, I'm just assuming that if I get the convolution bias by name, that this would represent the activations of the convolution, but I'm not positive on that either (as I haven't been able to see what they are).

**GCMLE `predict_json()` For Reference**

```
def predict_json(project, model, instances, version=None):
"""Send json data to a deployed model for prediction.

Args:
    project (str): project where the Cloud ML Engine Model is deployed.
    model (str): model name.
    instances ([Mapping[str: Any]]): Keys should be the names of Tensors
        your deployed model expects as inputs. Values should be datatypes
        convertible to Tensors, or (potentially nested) lists of datatypes
        convertible to tensors.
    version: str, version of the model to target.
Returns:
    Mapping[str: any]: dictionary of prediction results defined by the
        model.
"""
# Create the ML Engine service object.
# To authenticate set the environment variable
# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
name = 'projects/{}/models/{}'.format(project, model)

if version is not None:
    name += '/versions/{}'.format(version)

response = service.projects().predict(
    name=name,
    body={'instances': instances}
).execute(num_retries=2)

if 'error' in response:
    raise RuntimeError(response['error'])

return response['predictions']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall approach is correct.

You can use [`saved_model_cli`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/programmers_guide/saved_model_cli#show_command) to inspect the tensor names of the inputs and outputs, e.g. (from the aforementioned docs):

```
saved_model_cli show --dir \
/tmp/saved_model_dir --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default
```

Might output something like:

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['x'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 1)
    name: x:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['y'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 1)
    name: y:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

You can see that the input `x` maps to the tensor name `x:0`.

Of course, finding the names of non-input tensors is a bit harder. If you're building the graph from scratch, you can give the tensor a friendly name by adding `name="XXX"` to the ops. Otherwise, you'll have to do something like dump the SavedModel, e.g.

```
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saved_model_pb2
s = saved_model_pb2.SavedModel()
with open("saved_model.pb") as f:
  s.ParseFromString(f.read())
print(s)
```